# vue checkbox insanity, how to toggle a global checkbox if all checkboxes inside it are true

Tags: javascript, vue.js, checkbox

how can i do a checkbox system with a structure like:
i have multiple checkbox groups and each of them got there very own checkboxes inside.
and if all children checkboxes inside are true then toggle the daddy checkbox to true.
if either one of the children are false, then toggle the checked="true" from the daddy checkbox to false.
the daddy checkbox should only be true if all of his own children are set to true.

i did a little codesandbox to show what i mean.

[This is the tale of the childrens and there daddy (checkbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-mahavira-tzp7c?file=/src/App.vue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your sandbox has been updated.
you were simply returning the checkboxes that are checked inside `checkGroupCheckbox` function.

you will need to check if the checked boxes length is equal to the length of all the boxes and update the checked prop of the current group.

```js
methods: {
    checkGroupCheckbox(group) {
      group.checked =
        group.checkboxes.filter(item => item.checked).length ===
        group.checkboxes.length;
    }
  }
```

updated fiddle can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-water-ud1b2).